# Python fails to launch command through subprocess - which exists and is in PATH - on TravisCI

Tags: python, subprocess, environment-variables, travis-ci

As part of my Python package, I am trying to launch `wine` through Python's `subprocess.Popen`. In a nutshell, (only) on Travis CI, although `wine` is in `PATH`, I am receiving the following error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wine': 'wine'`

What am I overlooking?

---

OK: The `wine` command is located in `/opt/wine-staging/bin`, which is also part of `PATH`. It is added in the `before_install` section of `.travis.yml`.

OK: Running `wine --version` in the `before_install` section works, showing the correct version of Wine.

OK: Checking `os.environ` confirms that Python sees the correct content of `PATH` including `/opt/wine-staging/bin`.

OK: Checking the contents of `/opt/wine-staging/bin` from my Python script with `os.listdir('/opt/wine-staging/bin/')` confirms that `wine` is present.

NOT OK: Running `subprocess.Popen(['which', 'wine'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()` from within the Python script does not yield any output at all (but also does not fail in a meaningful way).

NOT OK: Running `subprocess.Popen(['wine', '--version'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()` fails with `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wine': 'wine'`.

- [Relevant section in .travis.yml](https://github.com/pleiszenburg/zugbruecke/blob/f6fc1dc3194d4fc8a546d249530a6595c3a116a3/.travis.yml#L59)
- [Travis build](https://travis-ci.org/pleiszenburg/zugbruecke/jobs/585938590)
- [Python source code, lines 194 to 214](https://github.com/pleiszenburg/zugbruecke/blob/f6fc1dc3194d4fc8a546d249530a6595c3a116a3/src/zugbruecke/wenv.py#L194)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On openSUSE Linux, `subprocess.Popen` will inherit all variables from `os.environ` implicitly, even if the `env` parameter is changed. The following will work just fine:

```py
subprocess.Popen(
    ['wine', '--version'],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
    env = {'FOO': 'bar'}
    ).communicate()
```

On Travis CI's variants of Ubuntu, for some odd reason, the variables from `os.environ` are not inherited IF the `env` parameter is used like above. There are two ways to work around this: Either do not alter the `env` parameter or copy all data from `os.environ` into env and then alter it:

```py
# Workaround 1: Do not use "env"
subprocess.Popen(
    ['wine', '--version'],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    ).communicate()

# Workaround 2: Copy all data from "os.environ" into "env" before altering it
envvar = {k: os.environ[k] for k in os.environ.keys()}
envvar.update({'FOO': 'bar'})
subprocess.Popen(
    ['wine', '--version'],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
    env = envvar
    ).communicate()
```